# Is there a way to see who logged into my MySQL AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I know there must be a cloudwatch setting I'm missing. I look under CloudWatch metrics and see graph for DB connections, but that only gives me a graph, not an export text based report. Think Listener log in Oracle, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring servers. ServerFault.com would be a better place for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable general_log so that MySQL starts capturing ALL SQL Queries executed. These can be captured in form of a flat file; or even in a table general_log so that you can query this table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html

Comment: I checked in general log and couldn't find anything. What I'm looking for is who logged into the database, and from which IP address. I have given access to a few users, I want to know when they login, and from where.

Comment: i think for u important should be that what all queries they executed; what data they got.. just logging in and going away wont help u.. and this general_log gives u IP address also

Comment: The general log should show "Connect" events.  Your RDS admin user (or any user with the `PROCESS` privilege) can see who is logged in right now with the SQL query `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`.  Users lacking the `PROCESS` privilege can only see their own connections.  If you don't see the `rdsadmin` user logged in (that's a system user that monitors the server), then you don't have the necessary privilege to see other users' current connections.  @Deepak, feel free to add this to your answer, if you like.